# Remove double quotes in the content of text files

Tags: vb.net

I am using a legacy application where all the source code is in vb.net. I am checking if the file exists and if the condition is true replace all the `"` in the contents of the file. For instance `"text"` to be replaced as `text`. I am using the below code.

**vb.net**

```
Dim FileFullPath As String
FileFullPath = "\\Fileshare\text\sample.txt"

If File.Exists(FileFullPath) Then
    Dim stripquote As String = FileFullPath
    stripquote = stripquote.Replace("""", "").Trim()
Else
    '
End If
```

I get no errors and at the same time the `"` is not being replaced in the content of the file.

**Data:**

```
ID, Date, Phone, Comments
1,05/13/2021,"123-000-1234","text1"
2,05/13/2021,"123-000-2345","text2"
3,05/13/2021,"123-000-3456","text2"
```

**Output:**

```
1,05/13/2021,123-000-1234,text1
2,05/13/2021,123-000-2345,text2
3,05/13/2021,123-000-3456,text2
```

Comment: Don't. Use. `File.Exists()`!

Comment: Also, look at the `TextFieldParser` class, which can take care of this kind of thing for you.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Saying not to use `File.Exists()` should probably have a qualification. E.g. if I have a program which needs a lengthy process to create a file if it doesn't exist, I'd like to know if that file exists.

Comment: Are you completely sure that the "Comments" part will never have a double-quote in it? The way that the double-quotes work is that they are doubled-up inside the value to represent a single double-quote, e.g. file value = `"The colour was ""good""."` gives a text value of `The colour was "good".`

Comment: Hi @AndrewMorton, Even though the value in comments is `"The colour was ""good""."` then it should be translated as `The colour was good.`

Comment: No one seems to have articulated the actual problem with your current code. You are processing the file path, not the contents of the file. What is the value of `stripquote` when you call `Replace` on it? Why would that affect a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go about this depends on the potential size of the file. If the file is relatively small then there's no point processing it line by line and certainly not using a `TextFieldParser`. Just read the data in, process it and write it out:

```vb
File.WriteAllText(FileFullPath,
                  File.ReadAllText(FileFullPath).
                       Replace(ControlChars.Quote, String.Empty))
```

Only if the file is potentially large and reading it all in one go would require too much memory should you consider processing it line by line. In that case, I'd go this way:

```vb
'Let the system create a temp file.
Dim tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName()

'Open the temp file for writing text.
Using tempFile As New StreamWriter(tempFilePath)
    'Open the source file and read it line by line.
    For Each line In File.ReadLines(FileFullPath)
        'Remove double-quotes from the current line and write the result to the temp file.
        tempFile.WriteLine(line.Replace(ControlChars.Quote, String.Empty))
    Next
End Using

'Overwrite the source file with the temp file.
File.Move(tempFilePath, FileFullPath, True)
```

Note the use of `File.ReadLines` rather than `File.ReadAllLines`. The former will only read one line at a time where the latter reads every line before you can process any of them.

EDIT:

Note that this:

```vb
File.Move(tempFilePath, FileFullPath, True)
```

only works in .NET Core 3.0 and later, including .NET 5.0. If you're targeting .NET Framework then you have three other options:

1. Delete the original file (`File.Delete`) and then move the temp file (`File.Move`).
2. Copy the temp file (`File.Copy`) and then delete the temp file (`File.Delete`).
3. Call `My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile` to move the temp file and overwrite the original file in one go.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney, When I try your way to replace " from my files I get error using the Class System.IO.File.Move. It says too many arguments. Error: Too many arguments to Public Shared Overloads Sub Move(sourceFileName As String, destFileName As String). File.Copy works.

Comment: @pbj, my mistake. I checked the documentation to see if there was an overload that allowed overwriting and there is, but I didn't notice that it is only supported in .NET Core 3.0 and later. That includes .NET 5.0 but it does not include .NET Framework 4.8 and earlier. As you're using VB, you also have the option of calling `My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile` and it does have an option to overwrite the destination if it exists. Doing it as a single atomic operation is a bit nicer but there's little chance of the delete succeeding and the move failing, so using two operations is no big deal.

Comment: Hi @jmcilhinney, No worries. I could do `Delete` & `Move`, `Copy` or `My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile`. Which would be a slick way of doing?

Comment: Depending on your definition of "slick", I'd probably suggest `My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile`, because it does the whole lot in a single atomic operation. `File.Copy` and `File.Delete` is probably the safest two-step option, because that will just leave behind an orphan temp file if only the first operation works. If you use `File.Delete` and `File.Move` then you end up with the original file gone altogether if only the first step works.

Answer (score 2):

You can read each line of the file, remove the double-quotes, write that to a temporary file, then when all the lines are done delete the original and move/rename the temporary file as the filename:

```
Imports System.IO
'...
Sub RemoveDoubleQuotes(filename As String)
    Dim tmpFilename = Path.GetTempFileName()
    Using sr As New StreamReader(filename)
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(tmpFilename)
            While Not sr.EndOfStream
                sw.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine().Replace("""", ""))
            End While
        End Using
    End Using

    File.Delete(filename)
    File.Move(tmpFilename, filename)

End Sub
```

Add error handling as desired.

Answer (score 1):

TextFieldParser is probably the way to go.

Your code with a few changes.

```
    Static doubleQ As String = New String(ControlChars.Quote, 2)

    Dim FileFullPath As String
    FileFullPath = "\\Fileshare\text\sample.txt"

    If IO.File.Exists(FileFullPath) Then
        Dim stripquote As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(FileFullPath)
        stripquote = stripquote.Replace(doubleQ, "").Trim()
    Else
        '
    End If
```

Note the static declaration. I adopted this approach because it confused the heck out of me.

Comment: Why Static???  Also it seems he wants to remove single quotes.

Comment: Only trying to remove double quotes `"`.

Comment: @Mary - if the code is executed more than once why recreate it is why.